# angular ng-click ternary conditional

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm making a pagination system with the "next" button. The "next" button should increase the `page.currentPage` variable, but it should not do anything when it reached the maximum `numPagesTotal`.

How do I add this condition to the following `ng-click` expression:

```
<a ng-click="page.currentPage = page.currentPage + 1">Next</a>
```

I figured that I need another `block` variable that is set to `true` when `page.currentPage === numPagesTotal`, and do something like below:

```
<a ng-click="block || page.currentPage = page.currentPage + 1">Next</a>
```

How do I set `block` in the `ng-click`?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f17sLojb/4/), for reference

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected result? if the current page is the last page you dont want to show the next button?

Comment: I would move all this logic to the controller so your UI just has `ng-click=pageUp()`.

Comment: if 'currentPage == NumPagestotal', so maybe desactive the ng-click or something, because now they currentPage can be higher to number pages and this is bad

Comment: @marjes, I have edited your question to better explain the objective.

Comment: Ben, I thought of that option, but i need work with multiple tables, i need create Page1_UP, Page2_UP, Page3_up....etc, and multiple vars and i dont wanna make that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
<a ng-click="page.currentPage >= numPagin || (page.currentPage=page.currentPage+1)">next</a>
```

Comment: i hate "(", I try to do the same but without the parentheses, thanks Nicholas , this work

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching the problem correctly. You don't even need the extra `block` variable. Just do this:

```
<a ng-click="page.currentPage === numPagesTotal || (page.currentPage = page.currentPage + 1)">next</a>
```

But I would recommend, for clarity of the View, to make this determination in the controller:

```
$scope.next = function(){
   if ($scope.page.currentPage < $scope.numPagesTotal){
      $scope.page.currentPage++;
   }
}
```

and just call that function:

```
<a ng-click="next()">next</a>
```

Comment: thanks, it work too, but i try it, only in html side,

Comment: This is a cleaner way and separates the logic from the view. Much better to go this way than doing it in the HTML. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

{{(curPage*pageSize)+1}}-{{records=pageSize>count?count:(curPage == pagesCount-1) ? count:(curPage + 1)*pageSize}}  of  {{ count }}